# Determine Next Point on a Line Between Point A and B From A

Tags: c++, math, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have a 2D Coordinate system where The Origin Starts at the top Left
(Y Is higher as I move downward)
I am Given Two Points in Space, Lets Say Point A, and Point B.
How can I determine that next Point on the line From Point A to Point B?
For example, I have Point A(10, 10) and Point B (1,1)
I know the point I'm looking for is (9,9).
But how do I do this mathematically?
For say a more complicated Set of points
A(731, 911) and B(200, 1298)

I'm trying to move my mouse, one pixel at a time from its current location to a new one.

This doesn't work, but honestly I'm stumped where to begin.

```
int rise = x2 - 460; //(460 is Point A x)
int run = y2 - 360;//(360 is Point A Y)
float slope = rise / run;
int newx = x1 + ((slope / slope) * 1); //x1 Is my current mouse POS x
int newy = y1 + (slope * -1);//y1 is my current mouse Pos y
```

It almost works but seems inverted, and wrong.

Comment: Look up [Bresenham's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060046/drawing-lines-with-bresenhams-line-algorithm)

Comment: There are an infinite number of points on a line. What is your step value?

Answer (score 2):

You already have the slope, so to get the next point on the line (there are infinitely many), you have to choose a step value or just arbitrarily pick one of the points.

Given *A(y<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>)*, your goal in finding a new point, *B(y<sub>2</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>)* is that it must satisfy the equation: *(y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>) / (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>)* = slope.

To simplify, *(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) * slope = y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>*

You already have x<sub>1</sub>, slope, y<sub>1</sub>, and you can choose any arbitrary x<sub>2</sub>, so when you plug all those into the equation, you can simplify it further to:

y<sub>2</sub> = *(x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) * slope + y<sub>1</sub>*

---

To illustrate this with your other points (`A(731, 911)` and `C(200, 1298)`) and say you want to find a new point `B`, we can proceed as follows:

Find the slope first:

```cpp
float slope = (1298 - 911) / (200 - 731); // -0.728813559322
```

Choose `x` and solve for `y`:

*x<sub>1</sub> = 731, slope = -0.728813559322, y<sub>1</sub> = 911*
Choose *x<sub>2</sub> = 500* and solving for y<sub>2</sub>, we get:

```cpp
float y2 = (500 - 731) * -0.728813559322 + 911; // 1079.355932203382
```

So your new point is:

```
B(500, 1079.355932203382)
```

You can verify this new point still has the same slope to point `C`

Answer (score 0):

With `A = (x1,y1)` and `B = (x2,y2)` the line is (expressed in two same equations):

```
(1)   y = (x-x1)*(y2-y1)/(x2-x1) + y1
(2)   x = (y-y1)*(x2-x1)/(y2-y1) + x1
```

To find next point, put `x1+1` (or `x1-1` you know) in equation (1) and find `y` and also put `y1+1` or `y1-1` in equation (2) and find `x`.

You can decide which one is better choice. Take care of vertical or horizontal lines, where one of the equations won't work.

NOTE: do not cast floating point result to int. Do round instead.